# In ASP.NET MVC how to use another model as property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I have two model, one is Company, one is Province.

```
[Table("Company")]
public class Company {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProvinceID { get; set; }
    public ProvinceModel Province{
        get {
            // ????
        }
    }
}
public class CompanyContext : MyXsiteContext {
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my Province:

```
[Table("Province")]
public class ProvinceModel {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class ProvinceContext : MyXsiteContext {
    public DbSet<ProvinceModel> Provinces { get; set; }
}
```

How do I get my Company, which only save the ProvinceID, to reference the Province object so I can refer to the province.name in my view?

Comment: Notice this is probably about Entity Framework, not MVC, since your "models" are database-aware entities.

Comment: ok, I'll add Entity Framework to the tag.

Comment: Please, stop referring to "ASP.NET MVC" simply as "MVC". One is a framework, while other is a language-independent design pattern. It's like calling IE - "the internet"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to do it similar to how the navigation properties are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx).

So in the link they describe Course -> Department but for you it is Company -> Province.

Also, as an aside, if you are going to reference Province.Name in your view you might run into a [Select N+1](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/08/18/select-n-1-problem-how-to-decrease-your-orm-performance.aspx) problem so that might be something to account for (depending on your specific use case, which I'm not 100% across, just highlighting it as a potential "thing")

Comment: Yup, you pointed me in the right direction and I was able to load a dropdownlist of provinces in my company view.